# Dynamic url in liquid template - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

I am trying to add a dynamic link to email. The body of the emails is fetched and rendered using a liquid template.

I have added the dynamic link as below, but not sure if it's the most elegant way. Any help in this will be great. Below is the relevant part of the code.

```
class UserDrop < Liquid::Drop
  def search_path
    ActionController::Base.helpers.content_tag(
      :a,
      @user.email,
      :href => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.admin_users_url(
        search: @user.email,
        host: Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host])
    )
  end
end
```

Liquid template code

```
Email: {{user.search_path}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really clean this up with a drop of inheritance:

```
class BaseDrop < Liquid::Drop
  # shamelessly stolen from
  # http://hawkins.io/2012/03/generating_urls_whenever_and_wherever_you_want/
  class Router
    include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

    def self.default_url_options
      ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options
    end
  end

  private
  def router
    @router ||= Router.new
  end

  def helpers
    @helpers ||= ActionController::Base.helpers
  end
end
```

```
class UserDrop < BaseDrop
  def search_path
    helpers.link_to(@user.email, router.admin_users_url(search: @user.email))
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Max for the solution